# How we implement "Please wait ...." screen in flex when app is busy

Tags: apache-flex

I have a function that restores all of the default settings of my application. This process can take a bit of time, so I would like to implement a "Please wait..." modal popup to let the user know that everything is alright and the program hasn't frozen. Once the function completes its task, I'd like for it to remove the message, and resume normal behavior.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c5906da30c.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c5906da30c.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On start:

```
var waitingpopup:TitleWindow = new TitleWindow()
waitingpopup.title = "Please Wait ..."

PopupManager.addPopup(waitingpopup, this, true)
```

On complete:

```
PopupManager.removePopup(waitingpopup)
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't need to convey anything to the user other than "the app is still running", I think a more elegant method would be to just change the cursor:

```
mx.managers.CursorManager.setBusyCursor()
//do stuff
mx.managers.CursorManager.removeBusyCursor()
```

The cursor will change to a clock with spinning hands.  I'm not sure if there's a way to override this with your own animation, but it's simple and doesn't require you to design your own window.

Comment: In my experience this doesn't work well when rebuilding UI components. I'm assuming the asker needs to build a lot of UI or else it wouldn't be taking so long as to appear frozen. If the flash player is working hard to process a display it can't be bothered to render a custom mouse at the same time. An option I use is to change the text of the button to "please wait..." and change it back to normal after the render is complete.

Comment: I've used it when dispatching events that call the back end.  It works great when you're waiting for a responder to populate the model from the database.  I guess I didn't think that it would interfere with the GUI rendering.

Comment: The problem with the busy cursor is sometimes you can get weird behaviour out of it. For example, when I refresh a large datagrid and set the cursor to busy, sometimes I can mouse over other UI controls and the regular mouse cursor appears, while the FLEX busy cursor sits there running ontop of the datagrid. Yes, I have two cursors at once, which is not intended. I find the busy cursor to be rather buggy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PopUpManager to create a Modal PopUp with an animated spinner.  The Alert component does this.  You can always reference the Alert source code to see how it works.

Comment: any chance you could provide some real example?

Answer (score -1):

For those arriving late to this question, Adobe released a Throbber in 4.5:

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1283019

http://fusiongrokker.com/post/using-the-flex-4-5-busyindicator

http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2011/05/simple-animating-preloader-and.html

For example, run the following from the fusiongrokker link above:

```
        private function busyOn():void
        {
            throbberId.visible = true;
        }

        private function busyOff():void
        {
            throbberId.visible = false;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup width="100%" 
          paddingLeft="10" 
          paddingRight="10" 
          paddingTop="10" 
          paddingBottom="10">
    <s:BusyIndicator 
        id="throbberId" 
        visible="false" 
        rotationInterval="{rotationInterval}" />
    <s:Button 
        id="start" 
        click="busyOn()" 
        width="100%" 
        height="50" 
        label="start" />
    <s:Button 
        id="stop" 
        click="busyOff()" 
        width="100%" 
        height="50" 
        label="stop" />
</s:VGroup>
```