# Flex: how to call titlewindow when changing tab, before tab's UI components are built

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

My Flex4 app uses a tab bar as follows:

```
<s:TabBar id="tabs"/>
    <mx:ViewStack id="vs" height="100%" width="100%">
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Tab 1"  width="100%" height="100%">
            ...
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Tab 2"  width="100%" height="100%">
            ...
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Tab 3"  width="100%" height="100%">
            ...
        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:ViewStack>
</s:TabBar>
```

The app opens with Tab 1 by default. Tab 2 is not built yet.

The problem is, when I change tabs to Tab 2, Flex takes a very long time to build the Tab 2 UI components and display the tab contents. The app basically freezes during this process. I need to provide some indication to the user that he/she needs to wait several seconds.

I've tried using the Cursor Manager to create a busy mouse icon. This didn't work (e.g. the cursor only changes when Tab 2 completes building).

I'd like to simply display a title window while the tab builds. But, I don't know how to launch it when I switch the tab, such that the title window appears before and while Tab 2 is building.

I know that the mx ViewStack can have a `change=""` property, but when I use that the title window doesn't appear until Tab 2 completes loading.

I'm not sure how to implement a `callLater()` function in the below scenario.

Can anyone help me figure out how to trigger the title window so that it appears before and while Tab 2 builds?

References:

[How we implement "Please wait ...." screen in flex when app is busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453508/how-we-implement-please-wait-screen-in-flex-when-app-is-busy)

[Flex: Looking for design pattern to display busy cursor while my app is "busy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740583/flex-looking-for-design-pattern-to-display-busy-cursor-while-my-app-is-busy)

UPDATE 1:

With the `createDeferredContent` comment from David below and `setTimeout` comment from weltraumpirat in my previous post linked above, I was able to hack together a solution resulting in a busy cursor displayed while the content in tab 2 loads. Here's what I did:

Create Tab 2 as a component implementing the following:

```
<s:VGroup 
    ...
    preinitialize="preinit"
    creationComplete="start1">

    private function preinit():void {
        mx.managers.CursorManager.setBusyCursor();
    }

    private function start1():void {
        setTimeout(start2,100);
    }

    private function start2():void {
        // create mxml components
        myBC.createDeferredContent();

        // place any required actionscript code here
        mx.managers.CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
    }

    ...

    <s:BorderContainer id="myBC" creationPolicy="none">
        <!--- place all mxml code here to create layout -->
    </s:BorderContainer>

</s:VGroup>
```

A few notes:

(1) While a busy cursor does display before Tab 2 completes building, the app still freezes and when the user moves the mouse the busy cursor stays put on the screen while the default mouse icon (the arrow) moves around the screen as controlled by the user until Tab 2 completes building and gets displayed. Not ideal, but at least the busy cursor indicates the app is doing something. If I wanted to, I could replace the busy cursor with a titlewindow indicating busy, etc.

(2) Changing the timeout from 100 ms to 50 ms still produces good results. But reducing it to 10 ms causes the busy cursor to appear only when all components are built and displayed. It's to be expected that reducing the timeout below some threshold will cause such behavior. I wonder if this threshold for timeout value (e.g. somewhere between 10 and 50 ms) depends on the client computer? Or, if I used 100 ms, does that safely cover all client machines? (How do we know it will?)

(3) I would have expected that replacing `setTimeout(start2,100);` with `callLater(start2);` and deleting `creationPolicy="none"` should produce a similar result, but it doesn't (e.g. the busy cursor never appears and the app freezes for a few seconds until Tab 2 gets displayed). I've never used `callLater()` before, so maybe I did something wrong (?).

Comment: This is not the real solution, but try setting the ViewStack's creationPolicy to "all":  `<mx:ViewStack creationPolicy="all" />`. By default, the view stack uses deferred instantiation and won't create the non-visible views until it's needed. The real solution is to understand why your view in the 2nd tab takes so long to be created. Care to show that code or describe what it's doing? We might even be able to help you w/an approach that uses `callLater` (or the other ideas suggested to you) if we understand why your view takes so long to be created.

Comment: Setting the ViewStack's creationPolicy to "all" can make it faster but also means it will take much longer time when initializing the APP. Is there any heavy calculation other than UI components and layout construction, while switching to Tab2?

Comment: The delay in processing is just due to Flex creating and laying-out the various UI components in Tab 2. This tab involves a lot of forms, text areas, and a fairly complex chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have heavy calculations during Tab2 initializaition you can split them by small chunks and execute them consecutively using callLater mechanism.

Here is VERY simplified example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.managers.CursorManager;

        private var i:int = 0;

        protected function nc2_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.enabled = false;                
            CursorManager.setBusyCursor();
            callLater(initTab2);
        }

        protected function initTab2():void
        {
            var j:int;

            //Part of calculations
            for (j=0; j< 10000; j++)
            {
                i++;
            }   

            //Check if completed
            if (i<1000000)
            {
                //If not call again
                callLater(initTab2);                    
            }
            else
            {
                //Finished
                CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.enabled = true;
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:VGroup gap="10" top="10" left="10">
    <s:TabBar id="tabs"  dataProvider="{vs}"/>
    <mx:ViewStack id="vs" width="100%" >
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Tab 1"  width="100%" height="100%" >
            <s:Label text="Tab1 content"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent id="nc2" label="Tab 2"  width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:Label text="Tab2 content" initialize="nc2_initializeHandler(event)"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Tab 3"  width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:Label text="Tab3 content"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:ViewStack>

</s:VGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks David, unfortunately the delay is due to Flex creating the UI components and laying them out via mxml, and not AS3 code that I can group to run within a function such as `initTab2()`. Unless I could move a subset of the mxml code into a `<fx:Declarations>` block and execute that somehow using your method (example?).

Comment: You can convert mxml declarations to actionscript functions and execute them consecutively

Comment: I mean every mxml UI element can be created and added to parent in actionscript.

Comment: If I set a component to `invisible`, does this save any time for Flex to create/lay out? If so, I could turn components back to `visible` using your method for `callLater()`.

Comment: Hmm... I never thought of that... could be possible if used together with includeInLayout

Comment: Well, I tried setting all the components to invisible and includeInLayout to false just to see if it effected layout time, but it didn't seem to speed anything up.

Comment: Could I change the layout shown in the original question's posting such that the transition to Tab 2 doesn't occur automagically when the user clicks on Tab 2, but rather, clicking Tab 2 button causes the app to enter a function of my choosing, such as function `userClickedTab2()`? If so, I can place `callLater(goToTab2)` inside `userClickedTab2()`, where function `goToTab2` includes `tabs.selectedIndex=1`.

Comment: Can you move your tab contents into separate mxml module? Then it will be possible to defer creation of this module and add it to container later

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Tab 2 itself is basically one component. Inside that component there are other custom components. This is where all the complexity lies, I think. How to defer creation and add later?

Comment: It is generally done by Module component. But wait I have another idea. Need to test it.

Comment: I didn't succeed yet. My idea was to prevent tabBar's changing event, then "callLayter" function that sets selectedIndex programmatically. But despite adobe documentation says that changing event will not be dispatched it somehow gets dispatched that creates infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks David, I'm not that advanced so I can only think of simple things. What about replacing `tabBar` with a similarly-looking `menuBar` that sends the user's clicks to a function that sets the selectedIndex for the ViewStack (e.g. `vs.selectedIndex=1`) programmatically?

Comment: Worth trying. In menubar's change event you can callLater function that changes viewstack's index